# OutputStream getting reset

Tags: jsp, servlets, socketexception

In my code for streaming ogg/webm video from MySql DB:

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
while (is.read(content) != -1) {  // reading a byte array.
  os.write(content);
}
```

I am getting following exception.

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Please suggest me the way I can play a stream in servlet which is being embedded in JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding before writing to outputstream.

```
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, max-age=0");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Connection reset by peer: socket write error

means that the client has closed the connection before your write something. It could be because your DB operation is taking time and the client is timing out.

- Check your code if you are keeping the connection idle for sometime without writing anything.
- It could also be  that brower window was closed before the response is written.
- When user make a request, and presses the stop button.
- *(I am not sure it can be also this)* It can be server closing the connection due to socket being idle, increase the socket idle timeout value.